# Issue with Hazelcast active-passive WAN Replication

Tags: hazelcast

I have several active and one passive (no wan-replication element) Hazelcast clusters. 
When some item is added to the global WAN-Replicated map I see following message in the log of the passive cluster instance:

> Received wan merge but no merge policy defined!

However, as I understanded from the 'hazelcast-fullconfig.xml', there is default merge policy for the map (hz.ADD_NEW_ENTRY). Also, I tried to set it explicit.

So as I understand, wan-replication merge policy and map merge policy are different things.

According to the [manual](http://hazelcast.org/docs/2.4/manual/html-single/#WanReplication), passive endpoint should not have wan-replication element.

Any ideas how can I configure wan-replication for the passive endpoints? Have I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

In version 2.x, you should define wan-replication-ref (and merge policy) for passive side also.

See: 
testWANClusteringActivePassive test in

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/maintenance-2.x/hazelcast/src/test/java/com/hazelcast/impl/WanReplicationTest.java